# Is it ok to handle base class events in it's subclasses?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I have the following clases:

```
public class Base {
    public virtual void SomeMethod () {}
}

public class A : Base {
    public override void SomeMethod () {
        base.SomeMethod ();
        //Some other code
    }
}

public class B : Base {
    static int someVariable;
}
```

Then `SomeMethod` gets called from an instance of `A` and i would like to react to that in class `B` and modify `someVariable`, preferably in a static way because there may be multiple instances of `B` and `A`.

I came up with a solution to define a static event in the base class, then raise it in `SomeMethod` of `Base` and handle it inside `B`. Is it okay to handle base class events in it's subclasses? Or is there a better solution to my problem?

Comment: If `someVariable` is static, you might want to expose a public static method that modifies it and call it from `A::SomeMethod`

Comment: A static event is okayish.  You only need to subscribe it once, do so in a static constructor for the B class.  Keep in mind that it is active for the life of the program and you can never refer to a specific instance of A or B in your event handler.